# How to save path drawed in UIView

Tags: ios

I have a big issue.  I use **drawRect** in **UIView* to draw a line, erase,...

I want to save them, and then when I open up app again, it can draw line and erase continue.

How can I do this? How can I save old data and then load all, and let draw continue?
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build your path by points, you can add them to NSArray and save it.
After app reload you can check if there is exist any points to draw. Here how you can do it:

// create array with points. here you can create NSMutableArray and add points dynamically

```
NSArray *points = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(5.5, 6.6)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(7.7, 8.8)], nil];
```

// create path to file

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *yourArrayFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"points.dat"];
```

// save array to that file

```
[points writeToFile:yourArrayFileName atomically:YES];
```

And after that you can reload your app.

// load points array from same file

```
NSMutableArray *points = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: yourArrayFileName];
if (points) {
    // draw
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but it have a issue, when i use erase mode, i load points array, it is draw pen mode :(

Comment: Step1: I use pen mode, drawing some thing.
Step2: I use erase mode, erase some thing.
Step3: Save points drawing to database.
Step4: After reload app, load points from database.
Excatly: Draw pen mode and erase mode
Result: Draw only pen mode :(